# Get a fields maximum length

Tags: java, jpos

I'm using a Jpos generic packager and need to get the max length of a selected field for one of my methods. Is there any way to do this.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `GenericPackager.getFieldPackager(fldNumber).getLength());` method call

Here is an example:

```
import org.jpos.iso.*;
import org.jpos.iso.packager.GenericPackager;

public class Main {

    public static void main(String[] args) throws ISOException {

        ISOMsg m = new ISOMsg();
        m.setMTI ("0800");
        m.set (3, "000000");
        m.set (11, "000001");
        m.set (41, "29110001");
        m.set (60, "jPOS 6");
        m.set (70, "301");
        GenericPackager p =new GenericPackager("cfg/iso87ascii.xml") ;
        m.setPackager(p);
        System.out.println(p.getFieldPackager(11).getLength());

    }
}
```

This outputs:

```
6
```

Which corresponds to the Generic Packager File:

```
    <isofield
            id="11"
            length="6"
            name="SYSTEM TRACE AUDIT NUMBER"
            class="org.jpos.iso.IFA_NUMERIC"/>
```

Answer (score 0):

`ISOFieldPackager` should have `public int getLength()` method, is that what you're looking for?

Comment: Im looking for something that gives that value but i dont think i can use ISOFieldPackager
Im trying to get the length of a specific field of an ISOMsg and append values to it until it is equal to the max length of the field like a custom padding if that make sense.

Comment: maybe try to explain what exactly are you trying to do with an example or something

Comment: If your field is a fixed length field it will get padded at pack time. So I assume you have a variable length field, and you need to get the max length and pad it to the max length.  Getting the max length has been shown with an example by David Bergert. Though you probably need to know what the field packager is to populate  it using the correct data format.